# React/Detect a click happened in AngularJS in react web component

Tags: reactjs, angularjs, onclick, web-component

I'm using React as a web component in my Angular JS application. The template and controller/service are written in Angular JS, and we are showing that template using slot tag in React application. I want my React application to be notified about a click that happens in Angular JS.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm clueless as of now.